Getting the AWS_MSK_IAM error while using the Jobcloud PHP Kafka library
I am using the following repository https://github.com/jobcloud/php-kafka-lib for PHP Kafka integration and encountering the following error: "General error: Unsupported SASL mechanism: AWS_MSK_IAM". Can anyone help me with this?


$conf = [
                'bootstrap.servers' => 'kafkahost', 
                'security.protocol' => 'SASL_SSL',
                'sasl.mechanism' => 'AWS_MSK_IAM',
                'api.version.request' => true,
                'debug' => 'all'
            ];

            // Initialize Kafka producer
            echo "Initializing Kafka producer...\n";
            TL_Log::DEBUG("Initializing Kafka producer...");
            $producer = KafkaProducerBuilder::create()
                ->withAdditionalBroker($this->host)
                ->withAdditionalConfig($conf)
                ->build();




If I remember correctly Amazon MSK only supports SCRAM-SHA-512 authentication
